# Javascript - Detect if YouTube content is blocked by client's server and if so replace with image

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I have a website that uses YouTube videos in iframes. My problem is that some of my site's visitors are on business networks that block sites such as YouTube. For those visitors it appears as if something is wrong with my website. I would like to figure out a way to detect if YouTube is blocked and, if so, replace the iframe with an alternate .jpg image. I would like to note that on many of these networks the youtube video is replaced by the visitor's company's access denied page.

Comment: Have your tried using youtubes API? You will have more control over the video events. For example player ready state.

Comment: I have not but my issue is when software on the users network like barracuda blocks them from getting to YouTube at all.

Comment: But you want to know how to replace the video with a image if the video doesn't load. Well if you use the youtube API you can use evenlisteners to see if the video has loaded, if it hasn't then simply display the image.